# How do I receive multicast packets?

Tags: c++, multicast

I'm trying to receive multicast packets from a media server. This is the wireshark capture of an example packet:

[image: Multicast Example]
<sub>(source: [memecode.com](http://memecode.com/images/general/multicast-packet.png))</sub>

There doesn't seem to be any ports involved, just MAC address for source and destination. Most of the source code examples I've seen bind against a specific port when receiving multicast packets. e.g.
https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzab6%2Frzab6x2multicast.htm

I would like to be able to receive these packets on both Windows and MaxOSX (C++ apps in both cases, ie Win32 API and Carbon, although the Mac port is more important).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just create a UDP socket, bind it to the port, join the multicast group, and call `recvfrom()`.

But the packet you captured doesn't look like a UDP multicast packet. Possibly something between the routers? It doesn't have an IP header let alone a UDP header, which is where the IP and port information is,

Comment: Exactly... so I maybe it's not traditional multicast then? I know on Mac I might be able to get at them using BPF but I'd rather use the standard socket API if I can.

Comment: Would raw sockets be worth looking into?

Comment: It's not an IP multicast. You'll have to find out what it is and indeed whether it is an instance of the packets you're trying to receive before any progress can be made. I find it hard to believe that the server uses Ethernet multicast rather than IP multicast.

Comment: It is the right packet. I know how to decode the payload, there is a header of 24 bytes and then 12 x 24bit signed audio samples. You can see the negative samples that start with "FF FF". I might have to start with using libpcap just like Wireshark itself.

Comment: @fret, and user207421 it's been a few years ;) How did you fix this? Did the approved answer work for you? Is there a difference from client (sniffer) code whether its ethernet multicast of ip multicast?

Comment: @Aleksandarf at the time I used WinPCap to get the packets. Later on a realized 2 things: a) there was VLAN issues preventing me seeing the packets and b) I needed the right setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,...) to receive multicast. I stopped needing a solution when we changed to a different system in that organization.

Comment: @fret thanks for getting back on this 7 year old issue. I did post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67044110/code-snippet-receiving-ethernet-multicast-ipv4-mcast-00-messages-miserably-fai however there is 0 activity